# Interface or Class Inheritance

Tags: polymorphism

I am making an inventory system. Different inventory item will have different uses so i am thinking about making a base class called InventoryItem and derive Wood, Gold, Weapons and so on. This way all InventoryItems will share some basic functionality and can have their unique as well.

My questions are:

1. If instead i use a interface i cannot count on specific fields or variables as it only takes methods. Is there any reason to use interfaces?
2. If i use derived classes and have a List with mixed items from different derived classes i would need some code that goes through each class and casts it to the proper class to use its unique abilities. How is this best handled?

Comment: A key benefit of both interfaces and inheritance is specifically to avoid (2); you need to rethink your design in this light. Any complex design is almost certain to use both extensively, as it is their appropriate combination that really drives O-O development.

Comment: I'd ask this on the general programming stack where you'll get much better results; this isn't directly related to game programming at all.

Comment: you should specify the programming language you are using as they behave differently. For example as the accepted answer states C# allows getters and setters in addition to methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. If instead i use a interface i cannot count on specific fields or variables as it only takes methods. Is there any reason to use interfaces?

While this is basically true, interfaces may include getters and setters. So you can mimic variable members without actually using them.

Just a simple example:

```
interface IWeapon {
    unsigned int CurrentAmmo { get; set; }
    unsigned int MaxAmmo { get; }
    TimeSpan ShootInterval { get; }
    TimeSpan ReloadTime { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    void Reload();
}
```

> 1. If i use derived classes and have a List with mixed items from different derived classes i would need some code that goes through each class and casts it to the proper class to use its unique abilities. How is this best handled?

That's exactly the reason for using polymorphism. If done right, your system will automatically call the apropriate member, without forcing casts or any special handling. Have a look at the [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword.

Another short example:

```
class Drawable {
    virtual void Draw(RenderClass renderer) {
    }
}

// ...

foreach(Drawable d in Entities)
    d.Draw(myRenderTarget);
```

Derived classes can now do one of two things:

- Don't implement `Drawable::Draw` which will essentially redirect all calls to the base class (i.e. default behavior).
- Reimplement `Drawable::Draw` using the [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword to overwrite the default behavior.

If a member is marked as `virtual`, you'll always call the most derived `override` being available.

Using an [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) base class is similar, but compared to interfaces this allows you to already implement parts, while leaving others unimplemented (they'll have to be implemented in derived classes).

Comment: Thank you! This did set me straight. I will design the baseclass so that there will not be any need to cast it. :)